# I want a command that sends an embed with all the servers that the bot is in

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I created a discord.js bot and after some time I wanted to add a servers list command
that sends a message with an embed for each server containing: `Server Name`, `Member Count`, `Server Avatar (As The Embed Thumbnail)`, `Server Owner ID` and Most importantly I don't want anyone to be able to use this command except for me so maybe I add a constant with my ID?,
I can't really come up with a code for it, but anyways... here's the format of one of the commands:

```
if((args[0] === settings.prefix + "deletereactions" || args[0] === settings.prefix + "dr") && msg.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")){
        //deletereactions #channel
        let channel = msg.mentions.channels.array()[0];
        if(!channel) return;
        let db = client1.db("rbot");
        let collection = db.collection("reactions");
        collection.deleteOne({channel : channel.id}, function(err){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            msg.reply("**✅ Done!**");
        })
    }
})
```

and here's my command handler:

```
const settings = require("./settings.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = "my_mongodb_url";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
const moment = require("moment");
const { CommandCursor } = require("mongodb");

let client1;


client.login(settings.token);

client.on("ready", ready =>{
    console.log("Ready");
    mongoClient.connect(function(err, cli){
        client1 = cli;
    })
    client.user.setActivity(`${settings.activity}`, { type: 'LISTENING' })
})

client.on("message", async msg =>{
    let args = msg.content.split(' ');
    if(msg.channel.type !== "text") return;
    if(msg.channel.type === "text"){
        let db = client1.db("rbot");
        let collection = db.collection("reactions");
        collection.findOne({channel : msg.channel.id}, function(err, result){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            if(result){
                for(let i = 0; i < result.reactions.length; i++){
                    msg.react(result.reactions[i]).catch(err =>{
                        if(err) collection.deleteOne({channel : msg.channel.id}, function(err){
                            if(err) console.log(err);
                        })
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Command (Run Or Execute Function):
For 1 User:

```js
if (message.author.id != "YOUR ID") return;
```

For 2+ Users:

```js
let Owners = ["ID 1", "ID 2"];
if (!Owners.includes(message.author.id)) return;
```

Ex:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "eval",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if (message.author.id != "696969696969") return message.channel.send("Only Owners Can Use Eval Command!");

   //...
  }
};
```

Links:
[User#id](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id)
[Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: Thank you, that's how I can make the command only work for me, do you know how can I fetch servers info?